# verify credit status thru a web service sending the person's SSN

Tags: web-services

I'm looking for some sort of webservice that gives me the status of a person's credit score by sending their SSN, don't need details about the credit, just need to see the status whether is good or bad credit. Anyone has ever done that or does it even know if it exists? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to find anything free, and probably not anything as straight forward as a SOAP call, but there are ways to access credit report information over the internet programmatically . For example, google "Experian NetConnect"

Comment: Thanks bdk, any other service like Experian that you know?

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, no.

Comment: @FerretallicA, If you don't know an answer, please don't post "I don't know" style answers.

Comment: Are you sure that he doesn't know? Perhaps he's an expert in the field :-)

Comment: I didn't say "I don't know", I said "no".
If you would care to prove me wrong, please do so. The limitation is a legislative one, not technical.